# error in inaugural corpus in nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I have an error while running a program given in NLP with python..as follows

```
 import nltk
 from nltk.corpus import inaugural
>>> cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
...             (target,file[:4])
...             for fileid in inaugural.fileids()
...             for w in inaugural.words(fileid)
...             for target in ['america','citizen']
...             if w.lower().startswith(target))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/probability.py", line 1729, in __init__
    for (cond, sample) in cond_samples:
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <genexpr>
TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I am new to python,,what does this error exactly means..

Comment: What exactly did you try to do / expect to happen? Where did you copy that code from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is from *Natural Language Processing with Python* by Bird, Klein and Loper, page 46. Indeed there's a typo in the book. It has been fixed in the online version (http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html).

Change `file[:4]` to `fileid[:4]`, as moose suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `file[:4]`. [`file`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) is an object that does not support slicing (`[:4]`)

[nltk.ConditionalFreqDist](https://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.probability.ConditionalFreqDist-class.html) seems to take a list of tuples. Eventually you wanted to write `fileid` instead of `file`?